# Getting an integer from MySql using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am quite new to php and I have some problems with my final year project at school. I have an issue retrieving an integer from a Select statement using php.
I have 2 tables:

Table Camping :

```
capacity(int 11)
spot_nb (int 11)
location (varchar 20)
availability (varchar 1) //this can be 'Y' or 'N'
```

Table reservation :

```
reservation_nb (int 10 auto_increment)
spot_nb (int 11)
uin (varchar 8; null)
persons_nb (int 5)
price (int 11)
email (varchar 60)
```

And for php I have the following code:

```
$query5 = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(spot_nb) from camping where capacity=2 and availability='Y'");
$query5->execute();
$result = $query5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = (int) $result;
```

to get the max value from table camping and insert into reservation with this code

```
$query6 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservation (price, persons_nb, email, spot_nb) VALUES (:price, 2, :email, :id);");
$query6-> bindParam(':price', $campingNumber);
$query6-> bindParam(':email', $email);
$query6-> bindParam(':id', $id);
```

But every time query6 is executed, the spot_nb that is inserted is 1.

Thank you,
Alex.

Comment: Have you checked the query manually, for instance, using MySQL workbench?

Comment: Yes, and for this query the returned result is 11, what i need, but in php it's not working, I have no idea why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [**fetchColumn()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) instead of `fetch()`

```
$query5 = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(spot_nb) from camping 
                        where capacity=2 and availability='Y'");
$query5->execute();
$result = $query5->fetchColumn();
$id = (int) $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your query to

```
$query5 = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(spot_nb) as spot_nb from camping where capacity=2 and availability='Y'");
$query5->execute();
$result = $query5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = $result['spot_nb'];
```

Comment: I already tried and I get this error every time: _Undefined index: spot_nb in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/register.php on line 79_

Comment: print $result and check what you get in that array

Comment: if I print the result I get just a blank page

Comment: then there is issue with connection to database.check $conn